# Using secondary index for .lt() with .filter() in RethinkDB

Tags: json, database, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, reql

Currently trying to solve a problem by using **RethinkDB** to find those objects which has a `createdAt` date key with less than the given value by using [`.lt()`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/lt/).

The following query works just fine with [`.filter()`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/) and [`.lt()`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/lt/):

```js
r.db("databasename")
  .table("tablename")
  .filter(r.row("createdAt").lt(new Date()))
```

Using [`.between()`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/between/) I can pass the `index` as expected as:

```js
r.db("databasename")
  .table("tablename")
  .between(new Date("2020-01-01"), new Date(), { index: "createdAt" })
```

But still I need to pass a lower value (`2020-01-01`) as well not like with `.lt()` which is not the same.

**Question:**

Even though the first query with `.filter()` and `.lt()` works as expected, only issue is it's not using the [secondary index](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/javascript/) what I created.

Is there any way to use the secondary index with `.lt()` similarly like `.between()` or somehow with `.filter()`?

The documentation does not mention anything like that. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` doesn't use secondary indexes, `between` should be the best choice here. Just try using `r.minval` to define the lower key, then it should have the same behavior as `.lt(...)`

https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/between

> You may also use the special constants `r.minval` and `r.maxval` for boundaries, which represent “less than any index key” and “more than any index key” respectively. For instance, if you use `r.minval` as the lower key, then between will return all documents whose primary keys (or indexes) are less than the specified upper key.

```
r.db("databasename")
  .table("tablename")
  .between(r.minval, new Date(), { index: "createdAt" })
```

Comment: That seems to be working as expected, thanks for your answer!